# Directory traversal vulnerability apache2

Tags: apache, security, url-rewriting

Was configuring apache to avoid **Directory traversal vulnerability** on linux environment.Effected url look like below

> https://www.example.com/datamap/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/%252e%252e/etc/passwd

To fix this issue was configuring rewrite with 404 as below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^%252e%252e/?$ - [R=404,NC]
```

Was not able to fix. Help with where i'm i going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```